# ViewPager2 infinite scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, infinite-scroll, android-viewpager2

I've implemented custom calendar view on canvas and want to add it to `ViewPager2`.

I have an adapter to test scroll behavior:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(private val viewPagerView: ViewPager2) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

        private val colors = arrayListOf(
            R.color.green,
            R.color.indigo,
            R.color.blueGray,
            R.color.brown,
            R.color.color_orange_300
        )

        fun scrolledLeft() {
            //colors.removeAt(colors.size - 1)
            colors.add(0, R.color.brown)
            //notifyItemRemoved(colors.size - 1)
            notifyItemInserted(0)
        }

        fun scrolledRight() {
            //colors.removeAt(0)
            colors.add(R.color.green)
            //notifyItemRemoved(0)
            notifyItemInserted(colors.size - 1)
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.pager_item, parent, false)
        )

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = colors.size

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bind("item $position", colors[position])
        }

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            private val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
            private val root = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.root)

            fun bind(text: String, color: Int) {
                textView.text = text
                root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, color))
            }
        }
    }
```

A listener:

```
viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        super.onPageSelected(position)

        Log.d("abcd", "count: ${viewPagerAdapter.itemCount}")

        if (lastDirection == Direction.RIGHT) {
            viewPagerAdapter.scrolledRight()
        } else if (lastDirection == Direction.LEFT) {
            viewPagerAdapter.scrolledLeft()
        }
    }

    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, posOffset: Float, posOffsetPixels: Int) {
        super.onPageScrolled(position, posOffset, posOffsetPixels)

        if (lastViewPagerPosition > position) {
            lastDirection = Direction.LEFT
        } else if (lastViewPagerPosition < position) {
            lastDirection = Direction.RIGHT
        }
        lastViewPagerPosition = position
    }
})
```

My logic was: we have 5 pages and starting on index 2. When scrolling right, deleting page with index 0 and adding new page to the end. When scrolling left, deleting last page and adding new page at index 0.
But if you comment out the lines, there will be incorrect behavior.

I don't want to use `Int.MAX_VALUE` or fragments!